# Why is it invalid to assign an integer value to a uint parameter in a C# method argument?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When assigning a default value to a `uint` parameter in a C# method argument, as shown in the first code block below, I am presented with the message "A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'uint'", whereas when assigning an int to a uint variable in the method body it is fine.

The code does compile; the warning is provided by means of the red, squiggly underlining in Visual Studio 2010.

```
void GetHistoricData(uint historyLength = 365) 
{
    uint i = 365; // this is valid
}
```

This is easily resolved by by using 365U in place of 365, thus:

```
void GetHistoricData(uint historyLength = 365U) 
{
    // method body
}
```

I am finding it really difficult to find a good explanation of why it is invalid to assign an `int` to the `uint` in the parameter when it is valid to do so elsewhere. Can anyone help me with the 'light-bulb' moment I am trying to find?

Comment: Red underlining should meant you can not compile. Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: I believe it is specific to your setup: warnings do not show up in my code with the "red, squiggly underlining".

Comment: A visual studio restart has provoked ReSharper into showing its light-bulb on the left when the underline is highlighted, indicating that this is just one of those ReSharper warnings.

Comment: Will you close it with my answer then? xD

Comment: There is no answer from you, just a comment.

Comment: There is now (I added one), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles for me, with compiler versions of both 4.0.30319.1 and 4.0.30319.17379.

If you're using an older version or a different compiler (e.g. a Mono one) then I suspect it's simply a bug.

EDIT: If it's compiling fine (and I can't provoke a warning at all from the compiler) then I *suspect* it's some plug-in, such as ReSharper. (Not that I'm seeing it in ReSharper either...)

I can't reproduce this in VS2010.

I would suggest that you *do* update the code to the one without the warning, just for the sake of readability - but it's still *valid* code without the change.

Comment: It complies for me, too. I should have mentioned that so I'll update the question. The warning is a red-squiggly line message in VS2010 rather than a build error.

Comment: This might be because of the way optional parameters work, what actually happens here is that the value get's injected into the calling method, apparently the compiler thinks it's not a good idea to do that without spitting out a warning

Comment: It does appear to be a ReSharper prompt after all; following a VS restart the R# lightbulb has now started to appear (sometimes) when the squiggly line is moused-over.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you're making a cast, so possibly also truncating the value, I *presume*, Visual Studio only *warns* you about a fact of potential problem could happen and *invites* you to make that cast esplicit. Especially if we are talking about default parameters, the default value should be clearly specified. Instead in case non esplicit cast, there is always a space on doubts, on what the cast value would be like.

Answer (score 1):

Red underlining usually means you can not compile. The code analyzer on VS sometimes bugs out, producing false error messages and warnings, that still compile. Restarting VS usualy gets rid of them.